# use of input validation requires entering the wrong number of inputs in c

Tags: c, validation

I've been attempting to add input validation to the ui for a piece of code that performs a scientific simulation. when values are manually entered that are flagged by the validation process they should look until one valid replacement value is entered - two are required by program for reasons I don't understand and sometimes when this validation loop runs the next input set is ignored (for example when wrong values for x2 were validated I was required to enter two values instead of one and then entering a value for speed was skipped entirely). I've posted the first section of the program only, brackets may need to be closed and return values added etc for it to run as is, but the issue is only with this section - I can add the rest if that would be helpful.

thanks for your help.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
double  time[10000], x1[10000], x2[10000], v1[10000], v2[10000];
double  m1, m2, k1, k2, r1, r2, w;
int     count, inmethod, savein, flappy;

/*in my experience it is good practice to only use variable names that c believes to be arbitrary - I'm using flappy as a flag having considered flag likely to be unusable.*/

time[0] = 0;
x1[0] = 0;  x2[0] = 10;
v1[0] = 0;  v2[0] = 0;
m1 = 5;     m2 = 5;
k1 = 5;     k2 = 5;
r1 = 5;     r2 = 10;
w = 0;

sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &inmethod);

if((argc == 2) && ((inmethod == 1) || (inmethod == 0)))
{
}

else
{
    printf("enter 1 for file input or 0 to enter input via the keyboard. you will be able to save your input for future use.\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(inmethod == 0)
{
    FILE    *input;

    input = fopen("inputfile.dat", "r");

    fscanf(input,"%lf", &m1);   fscanf(input,"%lf", &m2);
    fscanf(input,"%lf", &k1);   fscanf(input,"%lf", &k2);
    fscanf(input,"%lf", &r1);   fscanf(input,"%lf", &r2);

    fscanf(input,"%lf", &x1[0]);    fscanf(input,"%lf", &x2[0]);
    fscanf(input,"%lf", &v1[0]);    fscanf(input,"%lf", &v2[0]);

    fclose(input);
}

else if(inmethod == 1)
{
    printf("system properties: \n");

    printf("please enter m1 then m2, separated by a space and followed by enter\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &m1, &m2);

    if(m1 == 0)
    {
        flappy = 0;

        while(flappy == 0)
        {
            printf("enter a non zero value for m1.\n");
            scanf("%lf ", &m1);

            if(m1 != 0)
            {
                flappy = 1;
            }
        }
    }

// why do things happen twice?

    if(m2 == 0)
    {
        flappy = 0;

        while(flappy == 0)
        {
            printf("enter a non zero value for m2.\n");
            scanf("%lf ", &m2);

            if(m2 != 0)
            {
                flappy = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("please enter k1 then k2, separated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &k1, &k2);

    printf("please enter r1 then r2, separated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &r1, &r2);

    //needs a validation condition

    printf("initial conditions: \n");

    printf("please enter x1[0] then x2[0], separated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &x1[0], &x2[0]);

    if(x1[0] < 0)
    {
        flappy = 0;

        while(flappy == 0)
        {
            printf("x1[0] must be positive, please enter it again.\n");
            scanf("%lf ", &x1[0]);
            if(x1[0] != 0)
            {
                flappy = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if((x2[0] - x1[0] - w) < error)
    {
        flappy = 0;

        while(flappy == 0)
        {
            printf("x2[0] must be to the right of x1[0], please enter it again. \n");
            scanf("%lf ", &x2[0]);

            if((x2[0] - x1[0] - w) > error)
            {
                flappy = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("please enter v1[0] then v2[0], separated by a space and followed by enter \n");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &v1[0], &v2[0]);
```

Comment: Did your print out what m1 and m2 values are after input? Comparing floating point values to 0 is problematic.

Comment: I could check that the masses are greater than error? I'll do the check now as well but it isn't just the masses that are causing problems.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and inspected the variable values in your IDE debugger?  If not, I would recommend learning how to use the debugger.  It is your friend.

Comment: Not sure this will correct your issue, but you should check the return value of scanf before using the value it should have filled

Comment: I've made the change I mentioned, I'll update the code on here as it seems a better way to do it. it didn't help. it's usually the velocities v1 and v2 that aren't read btw. not always but usually.

Comment: Change `scanf("%lf ", &m2);` to `scanf("%lf", &m2);`  (drop the space)

Comment: @oldprogrammer it sounds like a good idea, how exactly would I do that? I'm a physics student and we're taught everything so quickly that the basics of how to do everything properly is just left out, I'm trying to learn more about basic good practice but it's a slow process.

Comment: @doraj idiots question, but what should I check that it is?

Comment: @chux I've removed the spaces from my scanf and fscanf lines. it didn't change anything.

Comment: scanf returns the number of elements successfully matched and assigned : it will tell you if something wrong has been entered (like a space trying to be parsed for instance). if it doesn't return the number of elements you wanted to read, then their values can't be used

Comment: As @Doraj says, check the `scanf()` and `fscanf()` results.  I do not have the file your are reading to know how `fscanf()` may be failing, nor do I have your exact keyboard input.  But having code check the results should quickly point out the issue.

Comment: What is the value and declaration of `error`?

Comment: I removed the wrong spaces, I'll check through the program for the white space you mention and respond when I get back to coding - it may be tomorrow

Comment: oh and error is 0.000001 - it's defined above the start of the bit I copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `scanf("%lf ", &m2);` to `scanf("%lf", &m2);` in at least 3 places.

The extra space tells `scanf()` to scanf for following white space (which is OK as this is usually the `\n`), but to *keep* scanning until non-white space is entered.  That is the reasons for the need to enter 2 numbers.

The first `char` of the 2nd number, not being a white space, is pushed back for the following `scanf()` to consume.

---

Side notes:

Consider collecting your `fscanf()` and test the result.

```
// fscanf(input,"%lf", &m1);   fscanf(input,"%lf", &m2); ...  8 more
if (10 != fscanf(input,"%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &m1, &m2, ... &v2[0])) {
  Handle_InputError();
}
```

The space in `scanf("%lf %lf", &r1, &r2);` looks fine, but its functionality is the same as `scanf("%lf%lf", &r1, &r2);`.  `"%lf"` scans through leading white space with or without a leading `" "`.  Here too and in other places, suggest testing the result.

```
if (2 != scanf("%lf%lf", &r1, &r2)) Handle_InputError();
```

Comment: I'm going to check this out when I get back to coding, it may be tomorrow. thanks for what looks like a great solution with.

Comment: @user2989789 Separate thought: for user IO, consider changing from `scanf()` to `fgets()/sscanf()`.  Both work OK when input is "as expected", but the 2nd idea works better to recover from ill-gotten data.   Something like `char buf[100]; if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError(); if (1 != sscanf(buf, "%lf", &r1)) Handle_SyntaxErrro(); foo(r1);`.  BTW: Avoid mixing `fgets()` with `scanf()` in the same program.

Comment: this works and I've accepted your answer as it fixed my issue. concerning your comment and recommended good practice thingumumy I would probably need more understanding than I have to do that I'm afraid, I need validation to perform numerical checks in addition to standard checks (in essence - do these numbers make physical sense). would you be prepared to explain some of the stuff you've used so I can attempt to use it?

Comment: @user2989789 This is good practice to check input data.  After scanning in data do test like `if((r1 < R!_MIN) || (r1 > R1_MAX)) HandleOutOfrange(R1); if (V <- 0.0) HandleOutOfrange(V);` User input is evil - do not trust it until vetted.

Comment: okay, I'm layering that in now and I'll move it to other sections as it's needed there. I'm only checking that numbers make physical sense, if the marker says that the second mass is potato then he's going to get a seg fault though :p